# Подсчитать у скольких чисел в заданном интервале сумма делителей будет нечётной

Tags: c++, математика

Вам даны два натуральных числа А и Б. Посчитайте у скольких чисел в интервале [A;Б] сумма делителей будет нечётным.Ограничение (1<=A<=B<=1000). Не получается сделать правильную сумму, буду рад любой помощи.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 6, sum = 0, total = 0;
    for (int i = a; i <= b; ++i)
    {

        for (int j = 1; j< i ; ++j) { 
            if (i % j == 0) sum += j;//Тут проблема
            if (sum % 2 != 0) ++total;
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
    cout << "Total:" << total << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А само число надо учитывать как делитель? Вы его таковым не считаете, а 1 - делитель. Это верно?

Comment: что подразумывается под  суммой делителей, их количество или  их сумма?... P. S.  Harry  сделал правильное замечание

Comment: проблема в строке `sum = 0;` - внутри цикла Вы проверяете не сумму на нечетность, а все промежуточные суммы.

Comment: Само число надо учитывать. @KoVadim Вынести sum=0; в первый цикл не помогло, хотя должно было.

Comment: я нигде не сказал, что этого достаточно. Я просто намекаю, что эта строка точно не на своем месте

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо, я понял где оплошал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт, решение найдено.Исправленный код будет выглядеть так.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 6, sum=0, total = 0;
    for (int i = a; i <= b; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j<= i ; ++j) { 
            if (i % j == 0) sum += j;
        }
        if (sum % 2 != 0) ++total;
        sum = 0;
    }

    cout << "Total:" << total << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А можно посчитать этим кодом для диапазона a=10^8, b=2*10^9? Или (с использованием long long) до 10^18?

Comment: @MBo мне кажется немного нецелесообразно будет, этот код рассчитан не на такие объемы.

Comment: То-то и оно, что не рассчитан. Этот (квадратичный) алгоритм O(n^2) загнётся на 10^5. Harry предложил улучшение до O(n^3/2) , с которым можно работать, скажем, до 10 миллионов. А с применением математики получается константное время (по крайней мере, пока мы можем найти корень за константу). Если это задача с какой-то олимпиады/контеста, то там указываются ограничения на данные.

Comment: @MBo Я это понимаю, и отметил что у Harry интересное решение. В следующий раз буду более корректно задавать вопросы, извините.

Comment: Ну а предложенный мной ответ осознали на будущее?

Comment: @MBo Как же это красиво, без статьи бы не разобрался, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если считать 1 как делитель, само число - не считать, и работать перебором (хотя тут есть более хитрые варианты, выгодные при больших числах - например, факторизация на простые числа, подсчет произведения степеней нечетных простых в разложении и на основе этого получение четности суммы делителей. Может, есть способы и еще хитрее, не знаю...) - то я бы делал так, не считая сумму.

```
bool odd_d(int n)
{
    bool odd = true; // 1!
    for(int i = 2; i*i <= n; ++i)
    {
        if (n%i) continue;
        if (i%2) odd = !odd;
        int d = n/i;
        if (d == i) continue;
        if (d%2) odd = !odd;
    }
    return odd;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int a, b, count = 0;
    cin >> a >> b;
    for(int n = a; n <= b; ++n)
        if (odd_d(n)) ++count;
    cout << count << endl;
}
```

Comment: Метод решения интересен, но ваш вариант не исправен, вставляя [1;6] получается 5, а должно 3.

Comment: @Nereus Считаем... Для 1 - 1, нечетно; для 2 - 1 - нечетно, для 3 - 1, нечетно, для 4 - 1+2 - нечетно, для 5 - 1 - нечетно, для 6 - 1+2+3 - четно. Итого - 5. Где я неправ?

Comment: Мы считаем все делители, то есть включая само число. 4 /(1,2,4)

Comment: А вы больше херьте вопросы, которые вам задают! Первое, что я спросил у вас 50 минут назад - учитывать ли само число как делитель! Вы, простите, поступили по-человечески? ответили? Нет. Я вынужден был дать ответ, **указав свой вариант ТЗ**. Вы теперь с таким апломбом - мол, хрен работает. Естественно. Раз вы не даете ТЗ - получаете ХЗ. И, кстати, "мы считаем" - да ни хрена вы не считаете, как раз в своем коде вы **НЕ** считаете само число.

Comment: Извиняюсь, тут новичок, я просто не заметил эти комментарии под постом. Но можно было и не так резко реагировать, задача была четко поставлена. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Сигма-функция (σ1 [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9)) нечетна для чисел вида `p^2` и `p^2 * 2` (например, 16, 18, 25)

Количество таких чисел в заданном диапазоне можно посчитать несложным циклом или напрямую с использованием корня (если это не приведёт к ошибкам округления)

```
int odd_sigma(int n) {
     return (int)sqrt(n) + (int)sqrt(n / 2);
}

int odds_in_inclusive_range(int a, int b) {
   return odd_sigma(b) - odd_sigma(a-1);
}
```